# Product of two Linear Operators

Tags: linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces

Let $S(e_n)=e_{n+1}$ and $T(e_n)=e_{n+2}$ be two linear operators on the Hilbert space $l_2(N)$, the space of all sequences $\sum_{1}^\infty |a_k|^2 < \infty$, and $\{e_n\}, n=0,1,2,...$ is the standard orthonormal basis.

How do I find the formula for $ST$?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be $ST(e_n)=e_{n+3}?$

Comment: The elements of $l_2(\Bbb N)$ are defined by $\sum_1^\infty \vert a_i \vert^2 = 0$, not $\sum_1^\infty a_i = 0$.

Comment: @RobertLewis Edited. Thank you.

Comment: It's $\sum_1^\infty \vert a_i \vert^2$!  You still need to put the exponent ***2*** in!  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

By the way, $T = S^2$, so $ST = S^3$, and we can generalize Adrian's comment as $$S^k(e_n) = e_{n+k}$$ for any $k \ge 0$.